# ext4 flags to specify "extents" mode?

Tags: ext4

I've formatted a new filesystem with and without `extents` feature just to understand how this feature works. However, when I look at the inode field `i_flags` I see that this field always has zero value (for "used" inodes 2, 7 and 11).

Documentation (from Kernel.org) about extents says, that this flag should have 0x80000 bit set for inodes which use extents - but it looks like it's not accurate.

Can I have inodes with and without extents in the same filesystem? Should I rely on the `i_flags` to determine the way, how the `i_block` field is used? Or it is just one filesystem-wide flag in the superblock which dictates extents usage for all inodes?

Answer (score 1):

The `extents` flag is stored for each inode, so it is possible to upgrade an ext3 filesystem without extents to ext4, and then enable the `extents` feature in the superblock and new inodes would be created with `extents` enabled.  You should definitely check the per-inode flag to decide how `i_blocks` is being used for each file.